# VB: Need help splitting a string into 3 variables

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2005

I need to split one variable into 3 variables. For example I have a variable called `Data` and it contains AAA00000001. I need to have them be split between the "AAA", "0000000", and "1". I looked at the `Split()` function but didn't get a clear example for this situation. The reason I need to do this is because I want to store these 3 variables into fields for a MySQL database.

Comment: How d oyou want it to be split?

Comment: what are the requirements here.... letters, then a certain number of zeros, then another non-zero number?

Comment: I said in the question: I need to have them be split between the "AAA", "0000000", and "1"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the string is ALWAYS the EXACT same length and need to be split at the SAME place, you can use `Substring()`.

```
dim s as String = "AAA00000001"

dim s1 as String = s.Substring(0, 3)
dim s2 as String = s.Substring(3, 7)
dim s3 as String = s.Substring(10)
```

If they're not always the same length, you're probably going to need to use Regular Expressions.

Comment: Thank you. Thank goodness they will always be the same length. RegEx scares me :/

Answer (score 2):

Are the three subvariables always of the same *length*?

If so, you can use [Substrings](http://www.dotnetperls.com/substring-vbnet):

```
Dim substring1 As String = Data.Substring(0, 3)
Dim substring2 As String = Data.Substring(3, 7)
Dim substring3 As String = Data.Substring(10, 1)
```

Comment: Yes they will always be the same length. 11 characters long

Comment: The length applies to the substrings as well. The last digit in your example is 1, but if you expect this number to increment, affecting the middle substring of zeroes, another split method (such as Regex) will have to be used.

Comment: No the number will always be 1 or 0. Like on or off.

Answer (score 1):

`Split` will break your string apart based on a character, or group of.  It's not appropriate here, that is unless you're always splitting on `0000000`, which I doubt you are.

If you know that the first 3 characters will always be your first group, second 7 your next, and last character, your final group, you could do something like this.

This uses the `Substring` function, e.g.

```
Dim yourString as String = "AAA00000001"
Dim c1 As String = yourString.Substring(0, 3)
Dim c2 As String = yourString.Substring(3, 7)
Dim c3 As String = yourString.Substring(10, 1)
```